# Ionic setup issues on Windows 7

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to install Ionic on Windows 7 machine.

- First, installed NodeJS 6.1.0, It went fine
- Then, ran npm install -g cordova, Went fine
- Then, ran npm install -g ionic, Got error related to Python.
  Installed Python 2.7
- Again, ran npm install -g ionic, Got error related to Microsoft .Net
  Framework 2 SDK.
- Updated npm to 3.8.9, Still getting error related to Microsoft .Net
  Framework 2 SDK.

Are Python and Microsoft .Net SDK actually required? Nowhere I could find about this in the installation guides.

Comment: Could you place any error trace?

Answer (score 0):

no python and .net SDK are not required

you need to download Android SDK in the case of developing for android.
you can download android studio and download SDK from SDK MANAGER or simply download android SDK. In my case, I download the android studio and then used the SDk manager to download the SDK's.

You can download it from here [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)
Also ou need to have JAVA jdk installed on your system and you have to set
PATH for both android sdk , java and nodejs

add **PATH** in system variables to environment variable
to

C:\Program Files\nodejs\
C:\Users**SystemName**\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools
C:\Users**SystemName**\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin

the above paths are according to my system. The SystemName may differ on your system else will be the same.

You also need to set **User Variable** jsut above your system variable:

ANDROID_HOME  : C:\Users\SystemName\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk

JAVA_HOME     : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79

you may also need to install gradle using nodejs command
and add its user variable and system variable
like

GRADLE_HOME  :C:\Program Files\gradle-2.9
same in system variable(i.e PATH)

But first of all you need to download Node.js
I tried v6.0.1 but it is not compatible for ionic 2 for now, so you can download v4.4.x or v5.x from Node js site(sorry dont have 10 repo poits to post the third link)  for now and later use v6.0.x

now using nodejs command prompt you need to install npm http://blog.npmjs.org/post/85484771375/how-to-install-npm

after installing npm

install ionic 2 and cordova using

```
  npm install -g ionic@beta cordova
```

now Ionic is installed on your system.

To start a new project

```
ionic start Myproject --v2
```

and if you want to start a ionic project using typescript

```
ionic start Myproject --v2 --ts
```

Now give command

```
cd Myproject
```

to go to the directory of your project

after that, to test your app use

```
ionic serve
```

Comment: Is Android SDK required to be installed before proceeding with the Ionic installation?